# Is there a way to stream edit (sed) Exchange mail on receipt?

Tags: exchange, mac

My institution stream-edits incoming mail to add this text to the top of every email from external sources:

```
\n
[EXTERNAL to MyCompany received message]
\n
```

It makes the summary views unhelpful, since the first few lines of most emails are now boilerplate.  Is there a way to run the incoming mail on the client end though `sed` or something to conditionally remove the first few lines if they match this unwanted text?

Functionality as shown in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113998/whats-the-safest-way-to-pipe-an-email-to-a-script-via-procmail/114067#114067 might be what I'm looking for

I use Mac Mail to access an Exchange mailbox.

Comment: If you can make your case clear that the text is really useless, you may be able to convince the company not to add it in the first place.

Comment: Many have complained, but MyCompany is resolute in adding it.  I'll edit my post to clarify that the added text is unwanted at the client end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is better to change it on Exchange server side.
Not very familiar with Mac Mail, but if you use Outlook client, we could edit the subject or body:
1.In Outlook, open up the message that you want to edit. Go to Message > Actions > Edit Message.

2. You can make whatever changes you’d like, like fix spelling mistakes or make annotations.
3. When you close out of it, you’ll be asked if you’d like to save your changes to the message. Click Yes.
4. Now when you look at the email again, you can see that your edits are now included in the original email.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10-mso_o365b/how-to-batch-add-text-to-outlook-email-messages/0946feee-0b9b-4a62-86b5-8e6c99a732cf?auth=1

but if you want to batch to change the received messages, it may need a code such as the following thread:

https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-to-batch-edit-subject-line-of-outlook-emails.2964819/